# Menu Drop-Down using MySQL enum in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, enums

I want to simplify my drop down menu in laravel, any suggestions are open :)

This is my migration code:

```
Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->enum('hobby', ['Reading','Swimming','Other'])->default('Reading');
```

and this is my view code to create the menu dropdown (create.blade.php)

```
    <div class='form-group col-md-6'>
    <label class='control-label'>Hobby <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
    <select class='form-control select2' name='hobby'>
    <option value="Reading" selected="">Reading</option>
    <option value="Swimming" selected="">Swimming</option>
    <option value="Other" selected="">Other</option>
```

so far this code works ok but is it possible if i use @foreach to make it more simple? and how? or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In the create method of your controller get all the possible hobies and pass them to the view :

```
$hobies = ['Reading','Swimming','Other'];
return view('create', compact('hobies'));
```

In the view :

```
 <div class='form-group col-md-6'>
    <label class='control-label'>Hobby <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
    <select class='form-control select2' name='hobby'>
        @foreach ($hobies as $hoby)
            <option value="{{$hoby}}" selected="">{{$hoby}}</option>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: i make the array for edit function too, but the data didn't show up according to a previous data : this is my code for the edit function : @foreach($hobies as $hobby)
                           <option value='{{$hobby}}' {{ old('hobby') == $hobby ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$hobby}}</option>
                           @endforeach

Comment: I just add this  {{ old('hobby', $profile->hobby) so the full code are like this @foreach($hobies as $hobby) <option value='{{$hobby}}' {{ old('hobby', $profile->hobby) == $hobby ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$hobby}}</option> @endforeach

Comment: I also add the array code in edit function on Controller